# How can I get the output of DB2 command run by db2cmd?

Tags: go, cmd, db2

I wrote a Go cli program and ran it with Windows cmd.
It then executed the following command:

```
db2cmd -c DB2 RESTORE DATABASE DMSCNDB FROM "C:/DB" TAKEN AT 20180522033009 ON C: INTO DMSCNDB  WITHOUT PROMPTING
```

Here is the Go code I used:

```
cmd := exec.Command("db2cmd", "-c", arg)
buf, err := cmd.Output()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed restoring backup with error: %s\r\n", err)
} else {
    log.Printf("Successfully restored backup with command output: %s\r\n", buf)
}
```

Everything worked fined, except for the command prompt spawned by the `db2cmd`. Is there any way to get the output of it? How can I get the output of DB2 command run by `db2cmd`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer here: *https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002036.html*

So, just use the `-i` parameter like this:

```
cmd := exec.Command("db2cmd", "-i", arg)
buf, err := cmd.Output()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed restoring backup with error:\r\n%s\r\n", err)
} else {
    log.Printf("Successfully ran command with output:\r\n%s\r\n", buf)
}
```